# Ubuntu 14.04: Videos playing twice as fast; no sound

Tags: 14.04, sound, video, pulseaudio

I've got a really annoying problem where I have no sound on my machine, and Youtube videos are playing twice as fast. I've googled this and tried solutions to no avail; none of my Sound settings change anything (they're set by default to Analog Output (built-in audio) and Analog Stereo Output, but none of the other options change anything), doing pulseaudio -k doesn't fix anything, and doing pulseaudio afterwards gives me these errors:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Doing `pulseaudio -d` gives me:

```
pulseaudio: invalid option -- 'd'
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to parse command line.
```

I installed pavucontrol and disabled the video card as an output (in 'Configuration' tab I turned HDA NVidia profile 'Off'), and set Built-In Audio to Analog Stereo Output, but nothing. In the default sound settings I use the audio tester and get nothing, both for the Analog Output and Digital Output options. Makes no difference if I'm using headphones or not (when I plug them in they're detected as a third option).

...so I don't know what else to try. I'm running a normal set of speakers from the audio-out jack on my motherboard (z170-hd3 ddr3).

edit: This is what I get from running `aplay -l result`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: in pavucontrol output device tab, clic green button near analog soundcard to set it as default. what is aplay -l result (in a terminal)

Comment: Added results in OP.

Comment: try with ubuntu 16.04 (you can try sound just booting from cd )